# Add hotfixes (*.msu and *.exe) into Windows 7 install iso

Tags: windows-7, iso-image, windows-installation

I want to add hotfixes into my windows 7 install iso image. I have already found a solution:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b9beedf4-337b-4ba3-90ab-7b8910404575/windows-update-hotfix-injection-into-windows-7-wim-image-for-deployment?forum=w7itproinstall

But with this method, only ***.msu** files are added into the iso.

[image]

I have also some (65) hotfixes as ***.exe**:

[image]

Is there a way to include them into the iso image?

Source for the complete update installer: 
http://winfuture.de/downloadvorschalt,2671.html

Comment: I have always used Nlite for this task...https://www.nliteos.com/download.html

Comment: Only `.msu` are added, because the `.exe` must be run as post-installation. How to do that is dependent on the product you use, but dism might be unsuitable.

Comment: I have added them into the **SetupComplete.cmd**. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-a-custom-script-to-windows-setup